# join tables in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a query that will give me a table with a number of columns as the number of different values that I have in one column

My original table looks like this:

```
tester_ID|trial|result
```

[example for data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-M2TI5h7o0UWdVakw1anlQcDg/edit?usp=sharing)

And not every tester has to have result for every trial

I want to make something like that:

```
tester_ID|trial 1|trial 2|trial ....
```

[example for possible result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-M2TI5h7o0bDZzQ3phRUk2bTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The problem is I don't know how to make join in a loop
That will go over all the testers and result in rows that write every tester with his result

Comment: I am really struggling to understand this question... Information_Schema.Columns gives you a list of columns in the database (with their tables), can you use that to dynamically build your queries?

Comment: Please show some example data and the expected result.

Comment: You need to stop think in terms of looping, looping is a very bad thing when it comes to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you

```
create table tableA
(
    tester_ID int,
    trial int,
    result varchar
);

insert into tableA values
(1,   10, 'P'),
(2,   12, 'q'),
(3,   13, 'w'),
(4,   14, 'e'),
(5,   15, 'h'),
```

**Static Version, has the values hard-coded to pivot:**

```
select *
from 
(
    select tester_ID , 
    'Trail_' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by tester_ID order by tester_ID  desc) as varchar(10)) col            
    from tableA
) x
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([Trail_1], [Trail_2], [Trail_3], [Trail_4], 
                [Trail_5])
) p
```

**Or else  you have to go for dynamic version**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( 'Trail_' + cast(x.rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from tableA
                    cross apply 
                    (
                        select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by tester_ID order by tester_ID desc) rn
                        from tableA
                    ) x
                    group by x.rn
                    order by x.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select tester_ID, 
                    ''Timeline_'' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by tester_ID order by tester_ID desc) as varchar(10)) col

                from tableA
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon i hope so

Comment: I think your problem is at `cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by tester_ID order by tester_ID  desc)`: when I execute it I am getting just `Trial_1` for all the rows.

Comment: Yes you are right but i can update only if the question owner updates the question with required data

Comment: Yes, here is an answare, you have answared your question instead of editting it

Comment: thanks, but the problem is I don't know how many Trials there is

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want something like this:

```
SELECT r.tester_ID,CONCAT(r.Trail_1,r.Trail_2,r.Trail_3,r.Trail_4,r.Trail_5) AS trails
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
            SELECT tester_ID , 
            'Trail_' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY trial DESC) AS VARCHAR(10)) col            
            FROM tableA
            ) AS x
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(col)
                FOR col IN ([Trail_1],[Trail_2],[Trail_3],[Trail_4],[Trail_5])
            ) AS p 
        ) AS r
```

It is OK if there cannot be one `tester_ID` with two trails or trials.

P.S. Maybe it can be optimised ;)

Comment: thanks, but the problem is I don't know how many Trials there is